# Standard normal probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

I ran into this problem.

If $ξ$ is a random variable with a standard normal distribution and η is a random variable such that: $η = \left\lbrace\right. ξ$, if $\left\|ξ\right\| \le 2$
$, 
-ξ$ if $\left\|ξ\right\| \gt 2$

Compute a distribution of the number variable $η$.

I am not sure whether I understand what they want me to compute. Isn't the distribution of η just a density function  $φ(x) = \left(\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\right)$ for $x \le 2$ and $-φ(x)$ for $x \gt 2$?

Comment: Notice that if you have $-φ(x)$ then your probabilities will be negative, which cannot be the case

Comment: so the distribution of  η is $ φ(x) $ for $x \ge 2$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: η is $φ(x)$ for $x≤2$ and $x≥ -2$ because of the condition $∥ξ∥≤2$

Comment: Hint: eta is standard normal.

Comment: @Did how can it be proved? I think I still don't see what happens with $η$ when $\left\|ξ\right\| \gt 2$

Comment: You could try to identify $P(\eta\in B)$ for every Borel $B$ included in $\{x\mid\|x\|\leqslant2\}$ and for every Borel $B$ included in $\{x\mid\|x\|>2\}$

Comment: I tried it and I got $P(η) = 2Φ(2) - 1$ for $\left\|ξ\right\| \le 2$, then $φ(x) = P'(η) = 2Φ'(2)$ and $P(η) = 2Φ(2) - 2$ for $\left\|ξ\right\| \gt 2$, then $φ(x) = P'(η) = 2Φ'(2)$. Is that enough to show that $η $ ~$ N(0,1)$?

Comment: No idea what $P(\eta)$ is supposed to mean, nor why the Borel sets $B$ in my comment disappeared from yours.

Comment: Think of the one dimensional case, and keep in mind that $\xi$ is symmetric.